# web3.eth.getBlock is not working except in Firefox

Tags: javascript, ethereum, blockchain, smartcontracts, web3js

I have a strange error. This code returns an error in all browsers, except Firefox

try it on codepen
https://codepen.io/yoyoy13/pen/poVVxvN

```js
console.log('getblock');
         web3.eth.getBlock().then((theBlock) => {
            console.log('theBlock',theBlock);
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log('error theBlock',err);
        });
```

Comment: Questions asking for help with non-working code need to include an [mcve] in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I think that is because you are injecting `window.ethereum`

```
   web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
```

Probably versions of providers are different in each browser.

try this:

```
let web3;
if (window.ethereum) {
    provider = window.ethereum;
    try {
      await provider.request({ method: "eth_requestAccounts" });
    } catch {
      console.error("User denied account access");
    }
  } else if (window.web3) {
    provider = window.web3.currentProvider;
  } else if (!process.env.production) {
    // this is ganache cli
    provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:7545");
  }
```